# JQuery plugin combo woes: Fancybox and ContextMenu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, fancybox

I'm using two popular plugins with success for the most part:

http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

http://fancybox.net/

They both work fantastically. However, I cannot seem to get context menus working inside a fancybox. The normal right click menu is suppressed, so I'm led to believe there is a z-index clash somewhere. After checking and updating styles though I still can't get a context menu inside a fancybox.

They both work great separately however. Anyone combine these successfully or experience similar issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely (without your code I can only guess) need to call the contextmenu plugin inside of the fancybox onComplete callback

For example:

```
$.fancybox({
    //other initialization options
    // ...
    // ...
    'onComplete':function(){
        //call the context menu plugin here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your css files will do nothing probably as ContextMenu is adding 'zIndex: 500' and zIndex: 499' directly in it's js. Adjusting this to 99999 and 99998 worked perfectly.

Great plugins.